# How to repare corrupt ubuntu12.04 without loss any data?

Tags: kernel, bootloader

My ubuntu 12.04 system in not open it shows only black screen on booting time because accidentally i remove some file from media folder like sda1, but i am not sure that this is the main region to corrupt, and my all data already is saved in system. So, how can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 2):

Make a bootoble Ubuntu cd using another computer, plug it in, start your system from USB and select "Try Ubuntu without Installing" from bootloader menu. From there, you can use Ubuntu to recover your files using Ubuntu's file manager.

Plug another USB or hard disk or a usb and copy your files there perhaps.

Or if you've unmounted your sda1 partition (you said you removed it from /media folder, partitions are usually mounted there, you can use)

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
```

And then browse your files there.

Comment: Yes,  this is the best solution!  I always carry a live stick with me, just in case. I've saved  several Linux and Windows systems with it.